How to prevent the border radius from disortion when decreasing the height?
Steps To Reproduce

Create a fabric. js Rectangle Object with a fixed width and height.
Apply a border-radius to the rectangle.
Decrease the height of the rectangle significantly (e.g., reduce it to a value much smaller than the width).
Observe the distorted appearance of the border-radius, which may look uneven or visually incorrect, similar to the issue shown in the image.

Expected Behavior
The rectangle's border-radius should remain proportional and smoothly rounded, regardless of the height.
Actual Behavior
The border-radius appears distorted and behaves unexpectedly when the height of the rectangle is decreased.
Code :
       const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        let canvasWidth = 640;
        let canvasHeight = 640;

        canvas.setWidth(canvasWidth);
        canvas.setHeight(canvasHeight);

      const rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 145, // Center the rectangle within the canvas
            top: 145,  // Center the rectangle within the canvas
            fill: 'blue',
            width: 350,
            height: 350,
            rx: 20, // Horizontal border radius
            ry: 20  // Vertical border radius
        });

        // Add rectangle to the canvas
        canvas.add(rect);

        canvas.renderAll();
        

JSFiddle
Version Info :

Node Version : 20.16.0
Fabric.js : 6.4.0




UPDATE:
To solve the jitter issues, you can debounce the method which is explained, below, we can use JS to do this.
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
function action(){
  this.set({
    width: this.width * this.scaleX,
    height: this.height * this.scaleY,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
  });
}
const onScale = debounce(() => action());

rect.on("scaling", function () {
  onScale();
}) 



const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas")
let canvasWidth = 640
let canvasHeight = 640

canvas.setWidth(canvasWidth)
canvas.setHeight(canvasHeight)

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 145, // Center the rectangle within the canvas
  top: 145, // Center the rectangle within the canvas
  fill: "blue",
  width: 350,
  height: 350,
  rx: 20, // Horizontal border radius
  ry: 20, // Vertical border radius
  objectCaching: false,
})

    function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
      let timer;
      return (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
      };
    }
    function action(){
      this.set({
        width: this.width * this.scaleX,
        height: this.height * this.scaleY,
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
      });
    }
    const onScale = debounce(() => action());

    rect.on("scaling", function () {
      onScale();
    }) 

// Add rectangle to the canvas
canvas.add(rect)

canvas.renderAll()
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Fabric.js Adjustable Dashed Line</title>
    <!-- Using Fabric.js version 6.4.0 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@6.4.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>



You can use the rectangle scaling event to update the width and height so that the scaling is set to 1 and the rectangle height and width are updated.


const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas")
let canvasWidth = 640
let canvasHeight = 640

canvas.setWidth(canvasWidth)
canvas.setHeight(canvasHeight)

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 145, // Center the rectangle within the canvas
  top: 145, // Center the rectangle within the canvas
  fill: "blue",
  width: 350,
  height: 350,
  rx: 20, // Horizontal border radius
  ry: 20, // Vertical border radius
  objectCaching: false,
})

rect.on("scaling", function () {
  this.set({
    width: this.width * this.scaleX,
    height: this.height * this.scaleY,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
  })
})

// Add rectangle to the canvas
canvas.add(rect)

canvas.renderAll()
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Fabric.js Adjustable Dashed Line</title>
    <!-- Using Fabric.js version 6.4.0 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@6.4.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>




I try this when i change the height, then my rect postion something vibration why?

@yashchapani please share steps to replicate it?

https://jsfiddle.net/YashChapani/g0xm9tqv/3/
Please check out this replicate and below issue accurs
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R8wO43LqTtooamuRg_Cj_BELzmeqraG8/view

@yashchapani updated my answer

https://jsfiddle.net/YashChapani/g0xm9tqv/5/
Please check i update

@yashchapani is the issue resolved?

Issue resolved but new issue open when height change then some minor object vibration

Can you check below link to
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R8wO43LqTtooamuRg_Cj_BELzmeqraG8/view

@yashchapani because you dragged the resize below the bottom limit, it changed the position of the rectangle is my guess

So, how to prevent this issue occurs?

@yashchapani looks like a rare scenario can't you ignore it?

I can't ignore it,

@yashchapani updated my answer

https://jsfiddle.net/YashChapani/g0xm9tqv/5/
I update after update code then corner not work

@yashchapani the debounce code is missing

https://jsfiddle.net/YashChapani/g0xm9tqv/6/
check now

@yashchapani no issues happening for me,

Can you share me the working demo video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUhL1cxO4X0MXS4VaAKLlKpQh4kdroDL/view
see this video
